# does a proper variation through geodesics keep the length of geodesic fixed?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, examples-counterexamples

Let $\Gamma:]-\epsilon,\epsilon[\times [a,b]\rightarrow M$ be a proper variation through geodesics, must the length of the transverse curves $\Gamma_s$ be constant as $s$ varies ?

I thought the ellipsoid could give a counterexample, because it has two equators of unequal length. However, I read on Wikipedia that the shorted path between two points on the equator of an ellipsoid need not live in the equator. Thus, it seems that I don't understand an ellipsoid's geodesics very well and therefore not sure if it is a counterexample.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes.

Since each $\Gamma_s$ is a geodesic with domain $[a,b]$, therefore each transverse curve will have length $(b-a)|(\Gamma_s)'(0)|=(b-a)|\partial_2\Gamma(s,0)=(b-a)\sqrt{<\partial_2\Gamma(s,0),\partial_2\Gamma(s,0)>}|$. It suffices to show that $<\partial_2\Gamma(s,0),\partial_2\Gamma(s,0)>$ is constant as $s$ varies.

$$\frac{d}{ds}<\partial_2\Gamma(s,0),\partial_2\Gamma(s,0)>=2<\nabla_1∂ _2 Γ(s,0), ∂ _2 Γ(s,0)>=2<\nabla_2∂ _1 Γ(s,0), ∂ _2 Γ(s,0)>=0 $$.

The rightmost term in the above line is $0$, because $\partial_1\Gamma$ is Jacobi field (as $\Gamma$ is variation through geodesics), and the tangential part of this Jacobi field is $0$ ( because it is a fixed variation). It follows that $\partial_1\Gamma$ is orthogonal to $\partial_2\Gamma$, thus differentiating $<\partial_1\Gamma, \partial_2\Gamma>=0$ with respect to the second argument gives:

$$0=<\partial_1\Gamma, \partial_2\Gamma>'=<\nabla_2\partial_1\Gamma,\partial_2 \Gamma>+<\partial_1\Gamma,\nabla_2\partial_2\Gamma>=<\nabla_2\partial_1\Gamma,\partial_2 \Gamma>$$

($\nabla_2\partial_2 \Gamma=0$ because $\Gamma$ is variation through geodesics).

---

An explanation to why the tangential part of the Jacobi field is 0:

- $t\rightarrow\partial_1\Gamma(s,t)$ is a Jacobi field along the geodesic $\Gamma_s$, because $\Gamma$ is a variation through geodesics.
- The tangential part of the above Jacobi field will vanish at the end points, because the above Jacobi field vanishes at the endpoints (as $\Gamma$ is a fixed varitation at endpoints).
- The tangential part of a Jacobi field is a linear function times the velocity of the geodesic, thus if it vanishes at two points it must be identically zero.

Comment: How does the fact that the variation is proper/fixed at the endpoings imply that the tangential part of the Jacobi field is 0?

Comment: @FriederJackel  Hi Frieder, after reading my answer again I realized I don't know why I wrote that.

Do you have any thoughts about the question ?

Thank you

Comment: @FriederJackel  Hello, I added an explanation to why the tangential part of the longitudinal velocities (aka the Jacobi field along $\Gamma_s$) must be zero.